# Restlet Router can not match my url request

Tags: url, match, router, restlet

I have question.

When I request some URL to server, Server receive URL request. (client: android)

For example, client request URL is  `http://address:8182/signupUser`.

Absolutely i believe that signupUser method is called. (please, refer below my method form.)

```
@Post("signupUser")
public string XXXX(Representation entity){
..
}
```

Of course, Server message in eclipse console is very collect.

However router call other method "confirmUser".

I'm so confused. all URI matching is perfect. But, router is not work well.

please, refer bellow my currently source.

```
public class serverApplication extends Application {
    public Restlet createInboundRoot(){
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        router.attach("/signupUser", UserResource.class);
        router.attach("/confirmUser", UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

Actually, i not familiar with English. I hope that my question is delivered to you exactly.

Please, help me....

Comment: @Post("signupUser") is probably wrong try @Post("xml") or @Post("form") as appropriate to what you are sending this is the media type not the path.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your comment. But, i wonder that How router match my URL to method. @Post(MediaType) is right?

Comment: The Router that matches the URL path is created in the `createInboundRoot()` method, this router you set up has the next , the ServerRseource then matches the method and media type based upon the annotation.  yes `@Post(MediaType)`

Comment: Thank you. I understand your comment. it's very helpful. I misunderstand Router. So, i recheck the restlet tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, your sample code will work better as follow:

```
@Post
public string XXXX(Representation entity){
..
}
```

The @Post annotation(or @Get, etc) is not a container for path routing instruction.
This is the job of the Router.

The main idea is that:

1. define your paths and paths template thanks to Router instance(s)
2. because a resource is identified by its URI, attach to eachd istinct path a distinct Java class.

For some more ideas:

1. Routers leverage the hierarchical nature of URIs. You can define nodes in your tree (a node is another router), and attach Filter before a Router in order to mutualize behavior for a whole sub-tree. For example, you can protect a set of admin resources:

   Router adminRouter = new Router(getContext());
   admin.attach("/users/");
   admin.attach("/users/{user}");
   //etc.

   // attach adminRouter to the /admin root path, and protect it
   ChallengeAuthenticator guard = new ChallengeAuthenticator(getContext(), ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "realm");
   guard.setNext(adminRouter);
   // attach the guarded admin router
   rootRouter.attach("/admin", guard);
2. For example: "/contacts/{contact}" means the "the resource that represents a single contact". "/contacts" represents the list of contacts. Technically speaking, you can attach the same Java class (as you did in your sample code), but you will end up with complicated code. A ServerResource class really represents a resource and helps handling its state using the whole set of accepted methods (GET to retrieve the state, PUT to store it, DELETE to remove it, etc).

I hope this is a little bit clearer.

As pointed by the other answers, annotations accept media types parameters (support also query values). I suggest you to have a look at this page: http://restlet.com/learn/guide/2.2/core/resource/

Comment: Thank you. I read your comments. your comments are very helpful. 감사합니다.

Comment: I have a question.
In your comments "For some more ideas Number 2", you said "A ServerResource class really represents a resource". 
Then, in my case, Should i separate between "signupUser" and "confirmUser"? Right?
I think those two methods are related to User. 
If those two methods are separated, this (my) project could be flooded with too many classes.

Comment: first thought: don't use verb in your URL. A resource represent a state you want to expose (eg. a list of users, a user, the weather at Beijing, etc). Then you act on this state using protocol methods (ie. HTTP verbs such as GET, POST, etc). If you are really blocked, you can define some technical resources that represent no state, on which you act using @Post methods (perhaps "signup" is a good candidate). Don't think in terms of operations, think in terms of state to expose.